# JQuery: Checkbox won't stay Checked when toggling between buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I admit, still a noobie at jquery and I have a page with a total of 12 buttons / toggles (only 3 is shown as example) , which when clicked each one will pull up a php page with it set of checkboxes listed with products within a div on the advance search page.  Since there are alot of information between each checkbox list, it slows the system down so I had to create an event when clicked it pulls that checkbox information when needed from another php page.  Problem is... the checkboxes won't stay check when I toggle between the buttons.  I have tried to a fuction where it sets the localstorage item when checked but doesn't seem to work.  In so, need you help on how to make the checkboxes stay checked when going back to through each button / toggle.

So is there a way that will keep my checkboxes checked when toggleing? And How (please use code examples)

Is there a better way I could do to make this work more efficiently, so it will load the page faster?  If so, How?  (please use code examples)

KITE_PAGE.PHP (works the same for ball, hula hoop and other products)

```
     <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="product_chkKite101" name="product_chk" value=" Like Kite 101 " /><label >Like USA Kite</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="product_chkKite102" name="product_chk" value=" Like Kite 102 " /><label >Like Mexico Kite</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="product_chkKite103" name="product_chk" value=" Like Kite 103 " /><label >Like Canada Kite</label>
    </div>
```

NOTLIKE_KITE_PAGE.PHP (works the same for ball, hula hoop and other products)

```
     <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="product_chkKite101" name="product_chk" value=" Not Like Kite 101 " /><label >Not Like USA Kite</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="product_chkKite102" name="product_chk" value=" Not Like Kite 102 " /><label >Not Like Mexico Kite</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="product_chkKite103" name="product_chk" value=" Not Like Kite 103 " /><label >Not Like Canada Kite</label>

    </div>
```

Advance Search Page:

Html from Advance Search page

Buttons (again only three is shown):

```
    <ul class="category">
        <li><a href="#kite" class="category-btn kite-btn">KITES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ball" class="category-btn ball-btn">BALLS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hoop" class="category-btn hoop-btn">HULA HOOPS</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The Div where the pages will load into:

```
    <div id="product_container" >
        <div class="kite box" >
            <div class="tx-row" id='kite-in' >

            </div>
            <div class="tx-row"  id='kite-x' >

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ball box" >
            <div class="tx-row" id='ball-in' >

            </div>
            <div class="tx-row"  id='ball-x' >

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="document box" >
            <div class="tx-row" id='hoop-in' >

            </div>
            <div class="tx-row"  id='hoop-x' >

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery that retrieves the information when button is clicked

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var $content = $('.box');
        function showContent(type) {
            $content.hide().filter('.' + type).show();
        }

        $('.category').on('click', '.kite-btn', function(e) {
            if ($('#kite-in').is(':empty')){                                                                                                
                showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
                e.preventDefault();
            }else {                                                     
                $("#kite-in").load("/wp-content/themes/child/kite_page.php");
                $("#kite-x").load("/wp-content/themes/child/notlike_kite_page.php");                                        
                showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }); 
        $('.category').on('click', '.ball-btn', function(e) {
            if ($('#ball-in').is(':empty')){                                                                                                
                showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
                e.preventDefault();
            }else {                                                     
                $("#ball-in").load("/wp-content/themes/child/ball_page.php");
                $("#ball-x").load("/wp-content/themes/child/notlike_ball_page.php");                                        
                showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        $('.category').on('click', '.hoop-btn', function(e) {
            if ($('#hoop-in').is(':empty')){                                                                                                
                showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
                e.preventDefault();
            }else {                                                     
                $("#hoop-in").load("/wp-content/themes/child/hoop_page.php");
                $("#hoop-x").load("/wp-content/themes/child/notlike_hoop_page.php");                                        
                showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        $(".box").hide();
    });
```

An Additional Question to this as well: 
Is there a way to disable a checkbox with same class  (example:  class="product_chkKite101" ) when one is checked between pages?

Comment: is this the minimum code for reproducing the issue?

Comment: localstorage should work in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't staying checked.  Every time I click on a button / toggle again, it reloads the information.   I had my if statement with in my jquery in correct.

Updated jQuery

Had to add an id inside a div to each page.   Then checked to see if the id is there or not.  If it is not there, then upload the page.  If it is there, just use the current page contents.

```
    $('.category').on('click', '.kite-btn', function(e) {
        if ($('#kitechk').length){                                                                                              
            showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
            e.preventDefault();
        }else {                                                     
            $("#kite-in").load("/wp-content/themes/child/kite_page.php");
            $("#kite-x").load("/wp-content/themes/child/notelike_kite_page.php");                                       
            showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('finish')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first what you can do is use on click attribute for all checkbox and pass the current element and better use id also because it will be unique and only one for a one checkbox

```
 <input id="product_chkKite101" type="checkbox" onclick="checkChecked(this)" class="product_chkKite101" name="product_chk" value=" Not Like Kite 101 " /><label >Not Like USA Kite</label>
```

now in checkChecked function first make an empty array

```
var checkedCheckbox = [];

function checkChecked(ele){
   var id = ele.id;
   if ($.inArray(id, checkedCheckbox) !== -1)
   {
       var index = checkedCheckbox.indexOf(id);
       if (index > -1) {
          checkedCheckbox.splice(index, 1);
       }
   }else{
       checkedCheckbox.push(id);
   }
   localStorage.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(selected));

}
```

now to make checkbox checked when page is reload or when button is toogled you can run this code

```
var checkCheckedStorage  = [];
$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("selected") != null) {
    checkCheckedStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selected"));
        checkChecked = checkCheckedStorage;
    checkCheckedStorage.forEach(function(ele) {
      console.log(ele);
      $('#' + ele).prop('checked', true);
    });
  }
});
```

if this code doesnot get executed when toggling the buttons then what you can do is write the code inside a function again and call it from the toggle event of a button

Comment: Trying your approach.   Even tried putting in toggle event of a button, but maybe I am not doing that right.   It just seems that everytime I click on button, it reloads the page causing it to erase all other check marks.  I even click on the same button, and it erases the checked checkboxes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gahc2rqh/ here I have done similar thing not the same but similar

Comment: I think i figured out source of problem.  It is my if statement checking if the id is empty or not.   It is figuring that it is always empty therefore always loading the page over and over.  Now to get that part to work.